# Should this section of water line be replaced?

Tags: plumbing, water, steel, galvanic-corrosion

This is the water supply line coming into my basement. 4 feet below the ground (frost line). My house is from 1940 and I assume that everything in these pictures are original.

I recently converted from galvanized steel to pex beyond the water meter for my entire downstairs due to water pressure issues. I can't do the upstairs yet because I'm not ready to tear down walls and upstairs is getting full pressure so things are good.

Anyways, if I ask the city to shut off the water at the street then would I be able to safely unscrew either that short pipe or the valve? I would use copper and continue the run to my pex transition. I have a sawzall with appropriate blades for cutting steel.

During my project I tried unscrewing a few runs of pipe with pipe wrenches and one of the joints simply broke off instead of unscrewing so if that happens here then I'm not sure about how I would proceed.

We bought the house 3 years ago and it has looked like this the whole time.

Any insight is appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Were it my home I'd be replacing everything in the photo. Is that copper coming through the wall?

Comment: @isherwood I am 99% certain that it's galvanized steel from the street into my home. I added another picture to hopefully get a better angle.

Comment: Will the city replace up to their meter??

Comment: @JACK No. I called them and from the road to my house is all my responsibility; about 80-100 feet. The will happily shut off the water at the street for no charge though.

Answer (score 4):

This can be a problem with old galvanized pipe if you had pieces break inside I would expect the same or worse here. I would purchase a kit for an emergency repair because my experience has been when 1 piece crumbles the rest is in similar shape. You should look into driving some ground rods also years ago houses only had 1 ground the water pipe, I have worked in a community that removed the metal pipe and installed plastic but they did not install ground rods, people were getting shocked so it would be a good idea to add them now while you are working in that area. Changing from galvanized to copper don’t forget to get a dielectric Union this keeps the copper from creating a circuit with the galvanized pipe and electrolysis eating the pipe in short time. After seeing the latest photo I would plan to replace everything from the Union on the meter to the house. This still could turn into a can of worms but I have had fewer problems with heavy cast than galvanized, the galvanized usually corrodes where the threads are cut through the zinc coating just as yours probably will.

Comment: What is that piece between the grounding wire and the wall??  A pressure regulator??  Thanks Ed.

Comment: Not a regulator it looks like some type of grounding lug.

Comment: @JACK I added another picture to my post. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Can you link me to one of these "emergency repair kits"? I've found several results but I'm not sure which one would fit my needs.

Comment: I was thinking of a slip on collar with a compression seal granger, and my plumbing and electric store have them, your last pic shows not much room until you get to the meter so these may not help much. I as I added to my answer I would probably tackle it at the union these break less often in my experience.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent insight into my situation. I think I am competent enough to replace everything starting with the ball valve up to my meter and leave it alone where the grounding wire is attached. I assume I would attach a dielectric male union with copper sweat end in lieu of the ball valve so that I can do copper up to my meter? I can do a ball valve right before the meter if you think it would be beneficial. I've heard people say that you are not allowed to put a valve right before the meter but I would have to check with my water company to get a real answer.

Comment: Can you tell whether or not I currently have a dielectric union before my copper starts?

Comment: I cannot tell but with the amount of corrosion I doubt it, but being buried that could be the cause of the corrosion.

Answer (score 3):

You're right to have the city turn off the water at the street but I don't think anyone on this site will say you can safely remove the small pipe or valve. That being said, you've got a corroded mess on your hands. The gate valve needs to be replaced. You're going to have to cut a pipe, unless there is a union, to start disassembling this. Clean up the joint between the valve and the ground wire fitting.... **DO NOT REMOVE OR TAMPER WITH THIS. IT'S GROUNDING YOUR ELECTRIC PANEL.** Then try to unscrew this connection. If you're successful, you can replace the valve with a ball valve and continue with your conversion. If this connection twists off you're in trouble and will probably need a plumber to replace the line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the grounding rods. My good friend is a journeyman electrician and spoke the same words as you. I would have him bring my electrical up to par.