# How do I use this plumbing connector?

Tags: plumbing, steel, connectors, corrosion

I am looking to attach an unthreaded galvanized steel pipe to either copper or a new unthreaded pipe. See my previous post for details: [Should this section of water line be replaced?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/175153/42053)

Per https://www.ridgidforum.com/forum/mechanical-trades/ask-the-plumbing-experts/38067-connect-to-galvanized-pipe-without-threads I have found this coupling:

[image]

https://www.shamrocksupply.com/itemDetailFilterPH.action?RFP=IFD&IDP=Y&codeId=9241200

However, I cannot find any other pictures nor instructions for installing it.

Can anyone guide me? I'd rather not spend ~$25 on a coupling which may not work for my application.

---

Would this product be a better choice for my application?

[image]

[https://www.homedepot.com/p/Homewerks-Worldwide-1-in-PVC-Compression-Coupling-511-43-1-1H/206667870?MERCH=REC-*-pipinstock-*-202269928-*-206667870-*-N](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Homewerks-Worldwide-1-in-PVC-Compression-Coupling-511-43-1-1H/206667870?MERCH=REC-_-pipinstock-_-202269928-_-206667870-_-N)

The product page states:

> For connecting piping and repairs of PVC and galvanized pipe

Comment: That Ridgid forum also linked to a page on this site: http://www.philmac.co.uk/products/?pg=3 The link was broken, but maybe those universal couplings could work for you? (just noticed that is a UK site so... maybe not depending on where you are)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call AY McDonald at 800-292-2737, or visit their web site, or reference the [instructions for that fitting](https://aymcdonald.com/files/shares/3210-205_8-11_.pdf), or see the pictures below.

But really, the outfit that sold you the fitting has some responsibility to help you in this regard, no? Call Shamrock Supply and make them earn their vig.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And NO, that plastic coupler (we always call them "Moody Couplings", don't know why maybe a regional thing...) is not as good of a solve.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!